# Is there an equivalent of System.lineSeparator​() for just the carriage return?

Tags: java

Is there a standard library method available that will output `\r` where needed on Windows and nothing for Unix? (i.e. equivalent to [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) except without outputting the newline character at all)

- I have some unit tests that are checking that lines output to a
  logger are matching the expected values (tested via a stub).
- These are failing when ran on Windows, as the strings contained a
  carriage return — i.e. it will output `Foo::Bar` on Unix or
  `Foo\r::Bar` on Windows. This is the first time that I've seen a `\r`
  getting generated on its own.

This is obviously easy to roll my own, but want the code to be as obvious as possible for future developers so looking to avoid reimplementing if not needed. Not looking for 3rd party libraries that do this, just if it is something covered by the Standard Java libs.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to add those `\r` or the reason why you get those unexpected `\r` in the logger?

Comment: @jhamon the production code is working fine & will only ever run on Unix, so just looking to add them in the test really (so they work for all developers in the least hacky way). Am _curious_ as to what's causing it. Was wondering if it could be related to a double-colon that I have in my sample string, it's the only "unusual" bit to the test data

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to fix the output in ordre to get the same result output in unix and windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the tests are failing on windows, it means that you have code that *assumes* the line separator is `\n`. It sounds like somewhere in your code (either in application code or in test code) you have something like:

```
String removeLineBreaks(String str) {
    return str.replace("\n", "");
}
```

and this is obviously a bug: on Windows, it will leave the carriage return untouched.

You should try to find the buggy platform dependent code. For example, the above should be changed to:

```
String removeLineBreaks(String str) {
    // "\\R" works in Java 8+, use "\r?\n" in older versions. Thank you Joop for this!
    return str.replaceAll("\\R", "");
}
```

Comment: I was _sure_ this wasn't the case, but did a search of the codebase for `\n` and found that we were indeed doing this in a test utility class. One of those times you wish you'd searched for those 5 minutes longer before posting the question :)

Answer (score 3):

Well you could use:

```
System.lineSeparator().replaceAll("\n$", "")
```

This would remove the final newline (required on both Windows and Linux), leaving behind the carriage return `\r` in the case of Windows only.